# Good idea using ControllerAdvice to perform REST authentication of a request?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my current Spring Boot application i seem to hit a wall when trying to implement a REST request filter. My goal with the request filter was to read the header and body part and validate the incoming data and check if it meets the HMAC construction we are using.

So the request filter seemed not to work an alternative solutions is to use  @ControllerAdvice.

Then the request validation can be implemented very easy. But i am not sure if it normally seen as an incorrect usage of the @ControllerAdvice annotation.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GenericWebControllerAdvice {

    @ModelAttribute
    public void authenticationFilter(@RequestHeader(value = "Authorization") String authHeader, @RequestBody String payload) {
        // process authentication based on header info and body content

        //  calculate the hash and check if meets the security settings

        // if the hash fails throw an exception that returns a http status code
    }
}
```

Any comments on the solution  or alternatives that are better?

Comment: Have you tried Google?

http://massimilianosciacco.com/implementing-hmac-authentication-rest-api-spring-security

http://blog.jdriven.com/2014/10/stateless-spring-security-part-2-stateless-authentication/

Comment: @SteveHall yes indeed, have read this post. But unfortunately this implementation does not work under the Servlet 3.1 spec.

Comment: I think `spring-security` would be the best solution!

Answer (score 2):

No you should do the validation in the controller (ie method with `@RequestMapping`).

Spring supports JSR 303/349 bean validation. Thus if your request body is a POJO and you have the correct annotation Spring will automatically do the validation for you. There is a tutorial of that here:

http://www.leveluplunch.com/java/tutorials/017-validate-spring-rest-webservice-request/

As for request parameter validation (ie not bean validation) I have had to make my own transfer objects and exception handling. How you do global exception handling is covered in the Spring Reference guide but generally you extend and/or register a `org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleMappingExceptionResolver`. Ironically `@ControllerAdvice` can be used for exception handling but I find it better to extend and register an Exception Resolver. More info can be found here:

- https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc
- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-exceptionhandlers

**Edit based on OP comments and edits:**

If your doing authentication or some other request based validation/authorization its probably best to use an [Interceptor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html). [Reference doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor). `@ControllerAdvice` will probably not work as the request handling is too far a long. That is you want something before databinding happens.

Comment: I noticed that i did not express my question fully so i added some explanation. Thanks for pointing me out to the validation part, but this does not help me.

Comment: Yes I misinterpreted. That is is not validation but sort of authentication checking.